# Why are my images and background images so blurry on mobile device ( using bootstrap )

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

EDIT: This actually appears to be a bug with the mobile version of Chrome! In all other mobile and desktop browsers the repeated bg image displays completely normal. Chrome it is horribly distorted.

We are building a responsive site on Bootstrap.

I have a fixed pos nav bar at the top of the page with a simple 7x157px img set as the background. I am also using a similar repeated patterned background image later on the body. On the navbar there is a normal block level DOM image.

On desktop these look completely fine but when I view them on my Note 3 (1080p screen) both the patterned bg images and the static image on the header are going very blurry to the point where the pattern is lost and it looks like a mess.

I have tried setting the viewport, playing with background repeat and background size, and nothing seems to work. Is this possibly a Bootstrap thing or is the area just too small for this sort of patterned background? What confuses me the most is that the DOM level img is just as blurry even though it should just be displaying actual size (I’m not scaling it up or down with %s or anything).

I’m ill attaching an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: sure does sound like a viewport issue.  What is your viewport code?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=0">

Comment: I also had it as user-scalable=no and had the same effect

Comment: I don't know if I'm even doing this correctly, but what I typically use is `width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no`.  This has its drawbacks including not being able to zoom out on mobile devices, but it does seem to render correctly for width at least.

Answer (score 4):

Pixel density, dude.

Your device actually has way more pixels than it advertises. My tablet has more pixels than my desktop monitor and my high-def tv. It's a pretty annoying problem that reared its head when Apple released that awesome retina display.

The issue is that they wanted to their devices to boast an amazing resolution capability to make images pop ... but if they didn't fudge their numbers a wee bit, a respectable 800px-wide website would only take up half the screen on a ~1600px-wide iPad. And, even if you scale your viewport to the device width, any banner image you have that is 800px is still going to upscaled to 1600px - and there's your blurriness.

So, you need to create different images for different resolutions and serving with media queries, unless you want to waste your user's bandwidth. I feel your pain, but image generation tools help - all the photo manipulation software packages are equipped to do that.

I haven't tested with the Note but I presume that WebKit guidance will apply there as well.

Further reading:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/SafariImageDeliveryBestPractices/ServingImagestoRetinaDisplays/ServingImagestoRetinaDisplays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012449-CH3-SW1

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am confused because this isn't a large image I am stretching, it's a small one that's being tiled. Would I need to make the pattern image twice as large or half as small to get it to display correct? I am not sure I understand how that would make a difference though.

Comment: make is 14 x 300 rather than 7 x 15, for example? It just seems that at some level it's just pixels being repeated.

Comment: The unofficial rule is to have two image sizes - one regular size and another x2 the size of the original- then use media queries to display different background images for high resolution screens.

Comment: @Novocaine88 is correct... as I said, it's a pain, but we all have to do it and misery loves company.

Answer (score 1):

Android does target density scaling in order to accommodate the varying screen densities of the Android ecosystem. The Android browser targets a medium screen density by default, trying to emulate the size of elements as if the screen was an MDPI screen.

Using [this website](http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/), you can see that the result of this scaling is that `device-width` is `601 px` and `device-height` is `880 px` on the Nexus 7. Therefore, it falls within your `max-width: 720px` declaration and the background appears red.

[image: Screenshot]

You have to remember that the **Viewport Size** and the **Screen Size** are two different things altogether.

**If you do not want this behavior, you may add `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` to your `<meta name="viewport">` tag. This will disable the Android target density scaling: `device-width` and `device-height` will report the native screen resolution of the device.**

More information about Android's target density scaling is available in the [Android Developers' Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#ViewportDensity).

Comment: This definitively made a change in the layout, but for some reason this repeat-x pattern image is still blurring

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried a lot of different combinations of viewports, background sizes, repeats, positioning, etc. In the end the only way to get a reproducible product of the original was to take my 6x157px image and tile it in PS to be 1920x157px. The height of the bar is set manually to 157. This produced the desired result, a horizontally repeating background image at the same "zoom" as the desktop mode. I further tried bumping up the image again in photoshop to 4000x157px and it displayed the same, all good. I then reverted back to the original 6x157px and guess what, it's still janked. So my guess is that horizontally repeating pattern type images are acting unstable in modern mobile browsers, probably because of some strange zoom/ppi related stuff, and the safest bet is to create a mobile version of these type images which are larger than you need and just clips off the side. Please somebody step in and let me know if I am wrong.

Here's a little test site I put together for this:

http://ghostmounta.in/hotspot/

Go ahead in dev tools and change url('img/header_background3.png') to img/header_background.png, and img/header_background2.png to see and example.

Comment: Spoke too soon, tiled background images are NOT rendering properly! The only hack to get them to look close is to use a very large image bu even that is providing unreliable results.